# while loop with a wrong condition

Tags: python

The problem is:

> Write a program that first prompts the user to enter the number of
>   numbers to be entered and then uses a while loop to repeatedly prompt
>   the user for those numbers and adds the numbers to a running total.
>   When the correct number of numbers have been entered, the program
>   should print the average.
>
> You can assume the number of numbers entered is an integer greater
>   than zero and that each subsequent number is a float.

And the code i got so far..

```
number_of_entries = int(input('Please enter the number of numbers: '))
sum=0
i=0
while i<=float(number_of_entries):
        num = input('Enter the number')
        num=float(num)
        sum+= num
        i += 1
print(sum/i)
```

The error raised is

> EOF when reading a line

It doesn't tell me anything else. I suppose the condition of my while loop is wrong..or maybe the whole logic is weird..

the first line is given by the question
and i initialized the variables gonna be used in the while loop, 
then i summed up all the numbers entered and count the number of times it's looping, and finally, printed the average..

Comment: Can you please add the complete trace back , and Python version ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar complete trace? you mean the whole question? the version is 3.4

Comment: @Nil no, the complete error

Comment: @AnandSKumar It only says EOF when reading a line. nothing else

Comment: How are you giving the input?

Comment: Yes, your loop condition is wrong, it will ask for one number to much. It should be `while i < number_of_entries`, no float conversion is needed either.

Comment: @AnandSKumar It's a python learning program provided by the teacher, it  auto tests a few numbers after we run the file.

Comment: Then it's probable that the data is fed with data from a file or similar. For example if the file contains the numbers 3, 1, 2, 3 and ends there you'll get due to the loop condition a fourth prompt when the input file has reached end-of-file.

Comment: @skyking THX mate. it's working now. forgive me for being a complete dummie..XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the program is tested by redirecting stdin. If you for example has the file:

```
3
1
2
3
```

And run `cat filename | python your-script.py` the expected result would be that the program calculates the mean of 1, 2, 3 and print 2.0. But your loop condition is wrong so you end up running the loop one time too much and the last time the `input` function is met by end-of-file condition (closing stdin). The correct(er) would be:

```
number_of_entries = int(input('Please enter the number of numbers: '))
sum=0
i=0
while i < number_of_entries:
        num = input('Enter the number')
        num=float(num)
        sum+= num
        i += 1
print(sum/i)
```

the program is still not immune to evil input.

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar problem when prompting for user input using Sublime-Text as editor. Apparently the default sublime console cannot deal with user input.

http://www.bestpythonide.com/python-input-eoferror-in-sublime-text-2.html

suggests installing the package sublime-repl

I have not yet tried this though. If it works please update.

EDIT: Just tried this using the SublimeREPL plugin and it fixes the "input() causes EOFError".

Just need to fix the logic error i.e changing the <= to < as previously suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I try to prevent using variable names that are pre-existing in Python - such as 'sum'.

Is this what you're looking for? The example below works for me.

```
number_of_entries = input("Enter the no. of entries: ")
total = 0.0
num = 0
i = 0
while i < int(number_of_entries):
        num = input("Enter the number: ")
        num = float(num)
        total += num
        i += 1
print (total/i)
input("Press any key to close.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
choice = int (raw_input ("How many number of times , u gonna input the numbers"))
def num():
    global f;
    f = int (raw_input("Enter the number: "))
i = 0
sum = 0
while i < choice:
    num()
    i = i + 1
    sum = sum + f
print (sum%i)

#Hope this helps u
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.